# Is it possible to run HBASE on AWS but it stores/pointes to HDFS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hbase

**just wanted to know if this question is even relevant?**
I tried understanding many blogs but could not reach to a conclusion.

Comment: You need to be more specific. HDFS is a filesystem, HBase is a database which may run on top of HDFS. Maybe pointing to an article and asking what is not specifically clear

Comment: I understant Hbase runs on top of hdfs, I want to connect Hbase running over EMR and pointing to HDFS native. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: ` Is it possible to point it to third party cloudera hdfs` so you want to access an external HDFS filesystem from the HBase running on EMR?

Comment: yes, I want to point it to external hdfs system.

Comment: any upadte @gusto2 , I am still looking out for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run [HBase on Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/features/hbase/). And you can choose either S3 (via EMRFS) or native HDFS (on cluster):

> It utilizes Amazon S3 (with EMRFS) or the Hadoop Distributed Filesystem (HDFS) as a fault-tolerant datastore.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what do you mean by Hdfs on cluster. Is it possible to point it to third party cloudera hdfs with HBASE having jobs running in AWS-EMR.

Comment: I suspect, but don't know for sure, that you can configure HBase on EMR to use a remote HDFS cluster.